# Why is the Etymology tag excerpt missing some words on the Tags page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wiki

I was looking through the tag excerpts and I noticed the Etymology excerpt that appears on the Tags page doesn't match what appears on the tag pop-up tooltip, the [etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tagged questions page, or the [etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) full wiki page's excerpt section.

I don't see anything that stands out as the reason, especially since tags like [particle-ni](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ni) and [kana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kana) have both kana and parenthesis in the exerpt which shows up on the page.  Some long excerpts are trimmed to three sentences on the Tags page, but that's not the case here either, because there's a full line open.

[image: Etymology excerpt in four different views]

Is this a bug?  Looks this way on both Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it cuts off anything before the word "is," probably in an attempt to avoid restating the tag's name.  Clever in theory but buggy in practice.

The same thing happens to [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), but even worse:

> Applies to any question that is asked about the differences between two or more words or phrases and how to select the best one for a given situation.

becomes

> asked about the differences between two or more words or phrases and how to select the best one for a given situation.

**Edit:** Looks like this is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts).  They suggest that we rephrase our tag wikis so that their parser handles them better. :/

Comment: Your keen observation seems to be the case.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Oh, ew.  So they tried to make things better but seem to have made things worse...

Comment: This has been annoying me too and I also thought (being a programmer) that it might be a misfeature. Maybe tag wikis should be just predicates rather than sentences and we should design them to omit anything up to and including the copula?

Comment: @hippietrail That's what I started to try and do today (until I noticed this weird thing).  Like in this case, I would have changed the excerpt to start with "The study of the origin..." pretty much like the tags page shows it now.

Comment: Does the live preview show how it will be displayed finally? If not then leaving us with a guessing game is definitely a bug to be reported. Especially for those of us who can only queue up edit suggestions and not edit and re-edit until it's perfect. (ie most of us).

Comment: @hippietrail Jeff Atwood's answer includes examples, but it's unclear if this is an exhaustive list.  Preview would help but I don't think it's the answer--it feels like putting lipstick on a pig.  What would help more are better guidelines when writing the tag wiki in the first place--and maybe code to _detect_ redundant phrasing as you're writing the wiki and a _recommendation_ to get rid of it.  Computers can do a lot, but humans are still better at language.

Comment: @Amanda: Unfortunately I don't have a human or a Jeff Atwood here to tell me how suggested>voted>accepted edits will look so I can't address that problem but since there's code mangling the excerpts in one place but not showing what the mangling would do in the other I can at least attempt to address that problem. So I'm in the middle of filing a bug report.

Comment: Feauture request officially filed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95323/when-editing-tag-wiki-excerpts-show-a-live-preview-of-how-they-will-look-on-the-t